# Q1: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, kernel-density

I'm trying to estimate the steady state distribution of piecewise probability density function using the look ahead estimator. But getting the error

```
z[condition1] = (1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi) ))*np.e**(-0.5*((x[condition1]-y[condition1]+Q1-u)/sigma)**2. 
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1.
```

could anyone tell why that first conditional is not working?

```
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm, beta
from quantecon import LAE

from sympy import symbols
q= symbols('q')



## == Define parameters == #
a_sigma = 0.4
psi_0 = beta(5, 5, scale=0.5)  # Initial distribution
phi = lognorm(a_sigma)


def p(x,y):  
    u=80
    sigma=30
    b=0.2
    Q=80
    Q1=Q*(1-b)
    Q2=Q*(1+b)
    z = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=float)
    # Condition 1 indexes all elements where subformula 1 is valid
    condition1 = np.logical_and(y>0.0, x >=y-Q1)
    z[condition1] = (1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi) ))*np.e**(-0.5*((x[condition1]-y[condition1]+Q1-u)/sigma)**2)
    condition2 = np.logical_and(y<0.0, x >=y-Q2)
    z[condition2] = (1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi) ))*np.e**(-0.5*((x[condition2]-y[condition2]+Q2-u)/sigma)**2)
    condition3 = np.logical_and(y==0.0, x >=-Q1)
    #print(-0.5*((k_prime[condition3] + q - u))**2)
    j=-0.5*((x[condition3] + q - u))**2
    K=[]    
    for elem in j:
        print(elem)
        K.append(1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi) )*sp.integrate(sp.exp(elem),(q,Q1,Q2)))
    #z[condition3] = K
    return z  

n = 10000    # Number of observations at each date t
T = 30       # Compute density of k_t at 1,...,T+1

# == Generate matrix s.t. t-th column is n observations of k_t == #
k = np.empty((n, T))
A = phi.rvs((n, T))
k[:, 0] = psi_0.rvs(n)  # Draw first column from initial distribution
for t in range(T-1):
    k[:, t+1] = k[:, t]+  A[:, t]  

# == Generate T instances of LAE using this data, one for each date t == #
laes = [LAE(p, k[:, t]) for t in range(T)]

# == Plot == #
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ygrid = np.linspace(0.01, 4.0, 200)
greys = [str(g) for g in np.linspace(0.0, 0.8, T)]
greys.reverse()
for psi, g in zip(laes, greys):
    ax.plot(ygrid, psi(ygrid), color=g, lw=2, alpha=0.6)
ax.set_xlabel('capital')
title = r'Density of $k_1$ (lighter) to $k_T$ (darker) for $T={}$'
ax.set_title(title.format(T))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is check the values of `condition1` and the shape of all items indexed with it, `x`,`y`,`z`.  As you give it, the error message doesn't indicate which indexing is the problem.

I don't know anything about `LAE`.  It looks like it takes a function (here `p`), and some argument(s).  Here you are passing an `n` element array (`k[:,t]`). But there's no indication as to how that maps on to the `x,y` arguments of `p`.

Here's a simple example that produces this error:

```
In [204]: x=np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
In [205]: x[:,1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-9bea3f5be5f1> in <module>()
----> 1 x[:,1]

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

If the index is an array, it may make a difference as to whether it is integer or boolean:

```
In [212]: idx=np.array([1])
In [213]: x[:,idx]
...
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
In [214]: idx=np.array([1],bool)
In [215]: x[:,idx]
Out[215]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```